# AzureAD JWT Token Audience claim prefix makes JWT Token invalid

Tags: node.js, rest, jwt, adal, azure-active-directory

I'm using the 'adal-node' npm package to authenticate with an AzureAD. This is all working fine and I get a token back.

However, the when examining the 'aud' claim in the JWT token I see the audience GUID is prefixed with 'spn:'. I think this is causing me problems when I try to use the JWT token on an already existing Web API. When I authenticate via a WebApp using the same AzureAD the 'aud' claim is NOT prefixed with 'spn:' and I am able to called endpoints on the WebAPI.

Can anyone shed any light on this? This is last hurdle to get over after a lot of head banging getting this working.

Update:

Using the npm package 'azure-ad-jwt' to validate the JWT token with AzureAD as soon as I receive it gives me the error which I suspected is the problem - 'JWT audience is invalid'. It is expecting the 'aud' claim not to have the 'spn:' prefix. Where is this spn prefix coming from?

Here's my app.js

```
var adal = require('adal-node');

var activeDirectoryEndpointUrl = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/';

var options = {
    domain: '<AzureAD GUID>',
    activeDirectoryResourceId: '<AzureAD App Client ID 1>',
    clientId: '<AzureAD App Client ID 2>'
};

var tokenCache = new adal.MemoryCache();
var authorityUrl = activeDirectoryEndpointUrl + options.domain;
var context = new adal.AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, true, tokenCache);

context.acquireUserCode(options.activeDirectoryResourceId, options.clientId, 'en-us', function (err, userCodeResponse) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Use a web browser to open the page ' + userCodeResponse.verificationUrl + ' and enter the code ' + userCodeResponse.userCode + ' to sign in.');

    context.acquireTokenWithDeviceCode(options.activeDirectoryResourceId, options.clientId, userCodeResponse, function (err, tokenResponse) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(tokenResponse);
    });
});
```

Decoded JWT Token:

```
{
    "typ":"JWT",
    "alg":"RS256",
    "x5t":"XXXXXXX",
    "kid":"XXXXXXX"
}
{
    "aud":"spn:XXXXXXX",    // <<< Offending claim
    "iss":"https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXX/",
    "iat":1471355868,
    "nbf":1471355868,
    "exp":1471359768,
    "acr":"1",
    "amr":["pwd"],
    "appid":"XXXXXXX",
    "appidacr":"0",
    "e_exp":7200,
    "family_name":"XX",
    "given_name":"XX",
    "ipaddr":"XX.XX.XX.XX",
    "name":"XX XX",
    "oid":"XXXXXXX",
    "scp":"user_impersonation",
    "sub":"XXXXXXX",
    "tid":"XXXXXXX",
    "unique_name":"XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "upn":"XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ver":"1.0"
}
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: After raising a support ticket with Microsoft they have confirmed that the problem lies with the adal npm package. The version of the AzureAD api that it's using it old and needs updating. When they will update the npm package, I'm not sure. Alternatively, they suggested using the URI for the audience, and not a GUID.

Comment: Please suggest replacement npm for it ( adal-node seems abandoned

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be documented "by design"<sup>1</sup> for Azure AD.

In Azure AD's SAML 2.0 [Single Sign-On SAML protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#audience) describing the response fields, they describe the *audience* response value. Note the bold text at the bottom:

> #### Audience
>
> This contains a URI that identifies an intended audience. Azure AD sets the value of this element to the value of Issuer element of the AuthnRequest that initiated the sign-on. To evaluate the Audience value, use the value of the App ID URI that was specified during application registration.
>
> Like the Issuer value, the Audience value must exactly match one of the service principal names that represents the cloud service in Azure AD. **However, if the value of the Issuer element is not a URI value, the Audience value in the response is the Issuer value prefixed with `spn:`**.

So for better or worse, the answer for Azure AD SAML 2.0 seems to be either:

1. Change your Issuer Entity ID to be a URI
2. Change your implementation to strip the `spn:` from the start of the *audience* response value.

---

*<sup>1</sup> The [SAML 2.0 Core spec](http://saml.xml.org/saml-specifications) specifies the `<Issuer>` element not as a `URI`, but as a complex type `NameIDType`, a string with no format requirements by default. So we can feel annoyed that Azure AD is not happy with non-URI string. Having said that, **every** example Issuer in the spec **is** a URI, so maybe our annoyed self-justification has its limits.*

Comment: While the `NameIDType` itself doesn't specify any format, the SAML profile spec 4.1.4.2 specifies that the `<Issuer>` must have format `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity`, which requires a URI. The SAML Core spec 1.3.2 specifies that all URIs must be absolute.
So the SAML spec requires the issuer to be an absolute URI. But I have no idea why that would affect a JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

Still facing the same issue 2 years after. As @Adam Young posted in comments to his own question - replace audience id with audience URL and that will resolve the issue.