# Create user access token for AAD application using Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

For a test scenario I want to create an access token for an AAD Application with the `APPLICATION_ID` as `aud` claim.

I created a correct token using Azure CLI (after I authorized the Azure CLI Application using *Expose an API* view).

```
$ az login -u <USERNAME> --allow-no-subscription
$ az account get-access-token --tenant <TENANT_ID> --resource <APPLICATION_ID>
```

I tried something similar in Node.js using `@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth`.

```
async function getToken(): Promise<string> {
  const credentials = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithUsernamePassword(
    USERNAME,
    PASSWORD, {
      domain: TENANT_ID,
      tokenAudience: APPLICATION_ID,
    },
  );
  return (await credentials.getToken()).accessToken;
}
```

The code returns a Bearer token, but I got `401` when using it. It turned out, that the `aud` claim was set in a different way than the Azure CLI does. The Node code prefixes the value with `spn:`, which is a documented behavior for the SAML protocol (see [Audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol#audience) section).

I tried also to use the `../oauth2/v2.0/token` REST endpoint with `grant_type=password`, but wasn't able to get any token.

How can I create an user token with exactly `APPLICATION_ID` as `aud` claim?

Comment: Have you checked the **Important** in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) about ROPC flow?

Comment: @PamelaPeng Yes. It's used for `grant_type=password` approach. I got `AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.` as error message.

Comment: Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC. Is your account an Azure AD Account that looks like "xxx@{tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com"?

Comment: @PamelaPeng It's not a personal account. It's an Azure AD account but managed by another Azure AD instance (source: External Azure Active Directory, Creation Type: Invitation). Are there other authentication flows than ROPC, which can create user tokens programmatically?

Comment: You could use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) without user,  **Or** use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) with signed-in user. Code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/master#windows-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-nodejs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that Azure CLI does three steps to create the application specific access token.

1. Authenticates the user credentials via SAML.
2. Requests general user authorization using `grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1_1-bearer'`
3. Requests application specific authorization using `grant_type: 'refresh_token'`

I was able to create a valid token without `spn:` prefix using the REST API via [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

```
async function getToken(): Promise<string> {
  const credentials = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithUsernamePassword(
    USERNAME,
    PASSWORD, {
      domain: TENANT_ID,
    },
  );
  // Mimic Azure CLI`s 'az account get-access-token' to avoid spn: prefix
  const { refreshToken } = (await credentials.getToken());
  const resp = await axios.request<{ access_token: string }>({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`,
    data: qs.stringify({
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: credentials.clientId,
      resource: APPLICATION_ID,
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
    }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  });
  return resp.data.access_token;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add my comment as an answer:

When using [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)(means `grant_type=password`), we need the Azure AD Account of current tenant, but not the invited account. You could create a test AD user to obtain access token using this flow. For more details, see [here](https://joonasw.net/view/ropc-grant-flow-in-azure-ad).

**Note:** Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow.

If you would like to get the token without user login, [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) will be better.

If you would like to get the token with a signed-in user, [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) could be used. However, the user needs to be logged in on the browser every time when requesting to get the token.

Code samples using ADAL: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/tree/master#windows-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-nodejs

---

If you specify the resource as the {Guid}, the Audience value wil be prefixed with `spn:`. You could replace `GUID` with `ID URI`, looks like "api://xxx" or "https://graph.microsoft.com".

The simiar issue: [AzureAD JWT Token Audience claim prefix makes JWT Token invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978298/azuread-jwt-token-audience-claim-prefix-makes-jwt-token-invalid)

Comment: Thanks. It's not obvious to me, how to programmatically get the access token using _auth code flow_. The `adal-node` documentation looks quite general. Could you give some additional hints, please?

Comment: A newer simple using MSAL.js 2.0 with PKCE: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2